# Neo4J - find if value in array property of 2 nodes matches

Tags: neo4j, iterated-function

Hi I have a use case where I have a node with property which is array.

*

```
Node({name:'a', colors:['red','green','blue']})
Node({node:'b',colors:['blue','black','red']})
```

*

Now I want to find out what is matching value between 2 nodes among their colors property.I shoud be able to get the matching value so as to pass it on further in the query for processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (a:Node {name:'a'})
MATCH (b:Node {name:'b'})
RETURN filter(x IN a.colors WHERE x IN b.colors);
```

If you want to continue with the query:

```
MATCH (a:Node {name:'a'})
MATCH (b:Node {name:'b'})
WITH filter(x IN a.colors WHERE x IN b.colors) AS v
UNWIND v AS matchingVals
MATCH ...
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As mentioned how to capture this matching value in variable and pass further down to query. Lets say depending on this matching value I want to do something.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you'd carry the value over.

Comment: If you want the value to be a list don't use UNWIND. UNWIND expands the list into rows.

Comment: Thanks, this works. My complete use case is something like this I have list of Nodes and wanted to establish relationship between nodes depending on certain conditions. Every node has property1 which is array, and property2 which is also array , now to establish relation among these 2 nodes they should have property1 containing one common element, and then one matching element from property2